# Quantas imagens posso gravar num campo blob mysql?

Tags: sql, blob

Posso gravar várias imagens num só campo `blob`?

Ou terei que criar vários campos? `Imagem1`, `Imagem2` etc... ?

Queria saber se existe alguma maneira para fazer isso sem ter que criar vários campos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um campo `blob` guarda um conjunto binário de dados. Você pode armazenar mais de uma imagem, se transformar ambas em um único stream de dados antes. Isso tem dois efeitos colaterais imediatos: você precisa saber onde uma imagem começa e a outra termina, e você necessariamente terá um arquivo maior naquele campo.

Isso pode ser útil se você precisar compactar os dados - vários arquivos em um mesmo pacote compactado podem resultar em uma taxa de compactação maior do que vários arquivos em pacotes separados.

No entanto, acredito que o seu problema seja guardar várias imagens sem saber de antemão quantas imagens terá que guardar para cada registro no banco, certo? Nesse caso o ideal é guardar as imagens em outra tabela, com `chave estrangeira` para onde o registro vai ficar.

Comment: Depois supondo que uma noticia tem várias imagens, como poderia fazer a chamada de todas as imagens?

Comment: @MárcioAndré sugiro abrir uma pergunta mais específica para isso. Veja também a resposta do gmsantos.

Comment: @MárcioAndré para o seu caso temos uma relação 1 -> N (uma notícia pode ter muitas imagens). Por que não normalizar e criar uma tabela separada?

Comment: Já consegui me desenrascar a esse nivel, obrigado na mesma.

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente uma coluna `blob` é feita para armazenar uma imagem só.

Se você precisa armazenar mais de uma imagem por entidade, a solução para seu problema seria normalizar o `blob` para uma segunda tabela externa:

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]